# Creating A New Thread Results In Autorelease Memory Leaks

Tags: iphone, objective-c, multithreading, memory-management

I have used the following code to create a new thread:

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(backgroundMethod:) 
                                             toTarget:self 
                                             withObject:paramObject];
```

And then in backgroundMethod I have set up a new autorelease pool as per usual:

```
-(void)backgroundMethod:(id)parameter
{
   NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

   //method stuff here...

  [pool drain];
}
```

But somehow the autorelease pool is not working. When running the code, the output in the console is as follows:

```
2011-02-17 00:38:16.928 audioEngine[13670:af03] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object
0x4b22370 of class NSThread autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
```

I have used multiple threads in the same way before and had no similar problem - what am I doing wrong?

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks :)

**EDIT:** Ok this seems a bit weird - I created an autorelease pool in the method that the new thread is created from, and the problem disappeared. Any idea as to why this might be and what the right way to fix it should be? I'd rather not have a random autorelease pool in my code without knowing what it's actually doing and why the problem is gone.

**EDIT2:** Here's the code creating the main autorelease pool:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
    [pool release];
    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: You only have one drain? There is not another in the '//method stuff here...' part?

Comment: Where is that `detachNewThreadSelector:` call being made?  I.e. set a breakpoint there, grab the backtrace, and post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it's complaining that the detachNewThreadSelector: call is the one that isn't being made with an autorelease pool in place, and not something within the backgroundMethod function, so that when the backgroundMethod finishes executing, the thread object is being leaked.

Check that the thread (main thread) that creates the background thread has an autorelease pool set up.

Comment: Just checked and there is an autorelease pool set up on the main thread, so that's not the issue. Should it matter if it's [pool drain] or [pool release]? I've been googling the problem and both seem to be used.

Comment: Could you please post the code that creates the main thread autorelease pool? Is the code that creates the new NSThread running from the main thread?

Comment: Done. Yup, it's on the main thread (there's just two threads, the main one and the one with the memory leak).

Comment: Are you releasing or draining the main thread NSAutoReleasePool anywhere before creating the new thread? It sounds to me like it's either that, or that the call to the method that creates the new thread is happening somehow on another thread by mistake, maybe with performSelectorInBackground or something.

Comment: I'm not aware of any, it's the first time I've used multithreading in the project. I'll have a good hunt around though and see if I can find anything.